# Check box in react native

Tags: react-native

How to display multiple selected check box flatlist values in react native please provide the answer as  as possible.I had tried but I don't know how to get it.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to help you, we need to see what code you've tried and where you've gotten stuck. If at all possible, please include the smallest amount of code needed to show your issue. I would also recommend reading about [what makes a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to include useful code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Try the Following Link to select multiple checkboxes in flatlist

https://medium.com/react-native-weekly/react-native-contact-list-99ff04b7baf8